# alternate for @Html in Japid

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, japid

In play framework we use `@Html` in scala views if we do not want play to escape Html characters. Is there any alternate to this in Japid. I tried to import `play.api.templates.Html`  and tried `${Html` and `${Html.get` but they are not working. Am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Japid by default does not escape the string value of expressions to make it html safe, like what Play! does.

Reference: https://github.com/branaway/Japid/blob/master/documentation/manual/Japid_Generic_Engine.textile

In case you need to explicitly escape the string value of expression, you can use:

```
${escapeHtml(expr)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
~{expr}
```

~ means escape.